# Mapping array to sequential numbers via dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have an array:

```
classes = ["banana","mango","apple"]
```

I am trying to print this array in a specific format where in each element has to be numbered in a particular sequence.  The desired output is as follows:

```
classes = [{"banana" : 1, "mango" : 2, "apple" : 3}]
```

I tried using a for loop as follows:

```
classes = ["banana","mango","apple"]
counter = 0
dat = []
for x in classes:
    counter=counter+1
    d = x,":", counter
    dat.append(d)
print(dat)
```

While this prints

```
[('banana', ':', 1), ('mango', ':', 2), ('apple', ':', 3)]
```

this is far from what I require.  Can someone help?

Comment: I would suggest using Python's dictionaries for this purpose, instead of combining into an array

Comment: @nj2237 thank you.  I am new to python and hence didnt know that I could use two lists.  It really helped.

Comment: You *can* use 2 lists, but it's more efficient to use `enumerate` for your precise task (as in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `enumerate` the input list and reverse via a dictionary comprehension.

```
classes = ["banana","mango","apple"]

res = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(classes, 1)}

# {'apple': 3, 'banana': 1, 'mango': 2}
```

There seems to be no need to put this dictionary in a list, as in your desired output.